# Does the One Plus 8 Pro's IR camera work with Open Camera?

Tags: oneplus, ir-camera, oneplus-8-pro

I'm trying to figure out whether or not, the One Plus 9 Pro's IR camera

- Is exposed as any other camera?
- Is a special device that is not exposed as a camera, but only a proprietary feature of the special One Plus Camera app?

Was this IR camera ever exposed as a stand-alone camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not currently the Camera is not exposed through the official Camera1 or Camera2 API. It's only available in GCam and GCam clones (like LMC 8.4) (or other apps which use CameraX and JetPack), as the functionality is provided by a high-level extension to [`com.qti.chi.override.so`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247917/7425). It amounts to OpenCamera and other camera apps not being a JetPack app and relying on lower-level Camera 1 and Camera 2 APIs. And, GCam being CameraX, which gets the IR camera functionality through the  higher-level CameraX extension that OP provides.

For more information see my follow-up [*"What is CameraX and JetPack?
"*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/255893/7425)

Comment: How do GCam apps access this infrared camera then?

Comment: Through some proprietary Google extension.

Comment: @tsilvs major update ^ thanks for for the upvote.