# Can the OnePlus 8 Pro IR camera be re-enabled with LineageOS?

Tags: lineageos, oneplus-8-pro, ir-camera

OnePlus got into some heat providing an [infrared camera](https://www.theverge.com/2020/5/19/21263372/oneplus-infrared-x-ray-camera-8-pro-temporarily-disabled-privacy-concerns). They subsequently had to disable it,

> Therefore, we are already working on an OTA that we’ll push out in the coming weeks to offer the Photochrom filter while limiting other functionality that may be of concern.

Can this be re-enabled with LineageOS? Has this feature been hardware-removed in new devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Re-enabled on March 4, 2022.

The LinageOS device name for the OnePlus8 Pro is [`instantnoodlep`](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/instantnoodlep/). From that repo we can see [`instantnoodlep` is is based on OnePlus `sm8250-common`](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_instantnoodlep/blob/lineage-19.1/setup-makefiles.sh#L12). [This repo is the `android_device_oneplus_sm8250-common` which you can find on GitHub](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_sm8250-common) in it you'll see [a patch named *"sm8250-common: Unlock gc5035 camera"*](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_sm8250-common/commit/9c9e8bdcd2984bfec73e5f04c56eec848cb18563). The gc5035 is the IR camera, (camera without an IR filter).

> [**sm8250-common: Unlock gc5035 camera**](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_sm8250-common/commit/9c9e8bdcd2984bfec73e5f04c56eec848cb18563)
>
> This change lets us use gc5035 camera, which was blocked by OnePlus long time ago after people discovered its *magic* capabilities. By default only `com.oem.autotest` can use it, however if we replace the first character with a NULL byte, then `strncmp` returns 0, and thus we pass the check and allow everyone to use it.

All ROMs based on LineageOS should have this patch, if they're newer than the March 4, 2022 date.

---

Note: keep in mind [you **MUST** use an Camera app based on GCam. Stock Apps and OpenCamera will not work.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247915/7425)