# What is CameraX and JetPack?

Tags: camera

In this answer [I determined that OnePlus was shipping functionality in CameraX and JetPack extensions to `com.qti.chi.override.so`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247915/7425), but what are these things and how do they compare to the Camera1 and Camera2 API that all the open source apps seem to use.

Comment: JetPack is only relevant for developers.

Comment: @Robert I don't think you can defend that statement if you can't _otherwise_ explain to users why some Camera apps work (and can see a specific camera) and others can not. This question is here because of this comment, _"How do GCam apps access this infrared camera then?_" The answer is they see the camera that other applications can't because they're made with JetPack and use CameraX. And for that statement to be useful, I wanted a very little bit of that here.

Comment: To my knowledge the JetPack libraries are just wrappers that internally use the regular Android API. The focus of those libraries are ease of use and compatibility fixes for different devices and Android platforms (see e.g. the introduction of [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera)). But it doesn't get you really new functionality. Special functionality of manufacturer apps is often implemented as private API but JetPack libraries won't give you access to those APIs.

Comment: @Robert not true, [the linked question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247915/7425) has more information but OnePlus deploys the functionality for the IR camera in `com.qti.chi.override.so` rather than native Camera1 or Camera2. This is _new_ functionality. And that file seems to be a part of CameraX/JetPack

Answer (score 1):

A Medium article by [Steven *"Camera2 vs CameraX: A Comparison of Android Camera APIs"*](https://medium.com/@seungbae2/camera2-vs-camerax-a-comparison-of-android-camera-apis-5db2b5ff302e) says,

> One of the key differences between Camera2 and CameraX is their abstraction level. **Camera2 is a low-level API that provides fine-grained control over the camera’s functionality.** This makes it a good choice for developers who need to create custom camera features or fine-tune the camera settings. However, this level of control can also make Camera2 more complex and difficult to work with.
>
> On the other hand, **CameraX is a high-level API** that provides a more simplified and intuitive interface for accessing the camera. It abstracts away many of the low-level details of camera functionality and provides a set of pre-defined use cases that developers can choose from. This makes CameraX a good choice for developers who want to quickly and easily integrate camera functionality into their app, without needing to worry about the low-level details of camera functionality.

According to [developer.android.com,](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera)

> CameraX is an addition to [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack) that makes it easier to add camera capabilities to your app. The library provides a number of compatibility fixes and workarounds to help make the developer experience consistent across many devices.

And [JetPack is described as,](https://developer.android.com/jetpack)

> a suite of libraries to help developers follow best practices, reduce boilerplate code, and write code that works consistently across Android versions and devices so that developers can focus on the code they care about.